# variable counter is not incrementing with adding new booking objects

Tags: java, static, counter, dao

// Entity class for booking

public class Booking {

```
    private int distance;
    private static int bookingId = 1000;
    private int cabId;
    private int customerId;
    private int billingAmount;


    public Booking() {

        bookingId++;
        System.out.println(bookingId);

    }
```

}

// Service class for booking, I'm setting up all parameters here.

public class BookCab {

```
    public Booking bookCab(int distance, int customerId){
        Booking book = new Booking();


        CabDao cabDao = new CabDaoImpl();

        book.setDistance(distance);
        book.setCustomerId(customerId);

        book.setCabId(cabDao.getCabId()); //retrieving cab data from database

        if(distance>10) {book.setBillingAmount(305 + (distance-10)*25);}
        else if (distance <10 & distance>5) {

            book.setBillingAmount(180 + (distance-5)*25);
        }
        else if (distance <5 & distance>1) {

            book.setBillingAmount(100 + (distance-1)*20);
        }
        else    book.setBillingAmount(100);

        return book;
    }
```

}

// This is DAO Implementation for accessing the Database.

public class BookingDaoImpl implements BookingDao {

```
Connection connection = null;
PreparedStatement ptmt = null;
ResultSet resultSet = null;

public BookingDaoImpl() {};

private Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
    Connection conn;
    conn = DbUtil.getInstance().getConnection();
    return conn;
}

public void addBooking(Booking booking) {

    try {
        String queryString = "INSERT INTO Booking(bookingId, customerId, cabId, distance, chargingAmount) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)";
        connection = getConnection();
        ptmt = connection.prepareStatement(queryString);
        ptmt.setInt(1, booking.getBookingId());
        ptmt.setInt(2, booking.getCustomerId());
        ptmt.setInt(3, booking.getCabId());
        ptmt.setInt(4, booking.getDistance());
        ptmt.setInt(5, booking.getBillingAmount());
        ptmt.executeUpdate();
        System.out.println("Data Added Successfully");
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (ptmt != null)
                ptmt.close();
            if (connection != null)
                connection.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

}

// Driver class

public class MainView {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    BookCab bookCab = new BookCab();

    BookingDao bookingDao = new BookingDaoImpl();
    bookingDao.addBooking(bookCab.bookCab(16, 691744));


}
```

}

/* Output

```
    1001
    Data Added Successfully

    1001
    Data Added Successfully

    1001
    Data Added Successfully
```

*/

```
    Counter is not working  
    booking id is not increamenting
```

I've tried printing counter right after increamenting but its same there as well.

Comment: Posting only codes isn't going to tell us what is not working. By the way, I'm very sure there are missing codes - at least I don't see `Booking.getBookingId()` defined.

Comment: `bookingDao.addBooking` was called once, why do you have 3 rows in the output?

Comment: Should write some explanation about issue faced in this code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only create one `Booking` instance in your `main` (or, to be exact, you create a single `BookCab` instance and call `bookCab.bookCab(16, 691744)`, which creates the one `Booking` instance), which means it should print 1001.

If you run that application multiple times (which, based on your output, I assume you do), the `Booking` class will be loaded and initialized on each execution, so it will reset the counter back to 1000.

If you want the value of that `static` variable to live across executions of your applications, you must persist it in some file or DB table and load it when the `Booking` class is initialized.

P.S., you might want to store the current `bookingId` value in some instance variable, so that each `Booking` instance is associated with a unique `bookingId` value.

Comment: that's the answer if OP ran the snippet more than once

Comment: @Andrew given the code in the question and the output in the question, that's a reasonable assumption.

Comment: @Eran yes great solution, setting up db table to store 'bookingId' certainly helps in retaining this id every time i run this application.

Answer (score 0):

Your main method only creates a single booking, which will have Id 1001 every time you run the application.

Create a loop in your main method to make more than one booking, and check to see whether or not it's being incremented.

So change your main from

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    BookCab bookCab = new BookCab();

    BookingDao bookingDao = new BookingDaoImpl();
    bookingDao.addBooking(bookCab.bookCab(16, 691744));


}
```

to

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
        BookCab bookCab = new BookCab();
        BookingDao bookingDao = new BookingDaoImpl();
        bookingDao.addBooking(bookCab.bookCab(16, 691744));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

static variable increment will not help you solve overall implementation problem here, it simply works as you expect when you create multiple objects for Booking class but catch here is what if the application is restarted ?

The counter is set back to starting point which is 1000.

@Eran has already indicated about this issue in the comment.